# Possibility of an ios chatting app using alamofire and a backend server

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, sockets, alamofire

I'm fairly new to ios app development and came across an idea for an app that involves chatting. The flow of the app is fairly simple as it involves simple login and profile creation. As a lot of my experience comes from web development, I was planning on creating a backend server using node that communicates with the client-side (which will be written in swift), taking the core ideas from this [tutorial][1].

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly related, but if you don't mind changing plans a bit, as an iOS beginner dev using Swift and Firebase looks the easiest solution to me. I've seen many tutorials about the realization of a Chat App and although most them, paid and free, are just not good enough even as a starting project, i found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZEluKixqDA) to be pretty good quality wise, let's say in the ~30 hours of tutorial 50% of the work for a basic Chat App is already done.